# Extracting Decimal Numbers Using Regular Expression(python 3.8)

Tags: python

I was trying to extract some numbers from mail-data, here is my code:

```py
import re

f = open('mbox-short.txt','r')

x = f.read()

z = re.findall('^X-DSPAM-Confidence: (0\.[0-9])+',x)

print(z)
```

But when i try to print the output it comes out to be NULL.
Here is the link to the txt file:

http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt

Comment: I think `)+` should be `+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag in order for `^` to match at beginning of line anywhere in a string with multiple lines.

Also, you want to include the `+` quantifier inside the parentheses; otherwise, the match group will only match the last occurrence of several (if there can't be multiple occurrences, that doesn't matter much, of course) and you only match the first digit after the decimal point.

```py
z = re.findall('^X-DSPAM-Confidence: (0\.[0-9]+)', x, re.MULTILINE)
```